# Qcombobox remove and add item in C++ Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qcombobox

Creating a combobox in Qtableview2 column 1 and passing values from Qtableview1 column1
so i am storing column1 table1 values in Qstringlist and passing to combobox

```
void cymodel::rowvalues() {
    QAbstractItemModel* table1 = ui.tableView->model();
    QAbstractItemModel* table2 = ui.tableView_2->model();
    QStringList colvallist1;

    for (int r = 0, maxI = table1->rowCount(); r < maxI; ++r)
        colvallist1.append(table1->data(table1->index(r, 0)).toString());//store value in stringlist
        for (int i = 0, maxI = table2->rowCount(); i < maxI; ++i)//for all rows
        {
            const QModelIndex idx = table2->index(i, 1);
            QComboBox* combo = qobject_cast<QComboBox*>(ui.tableView_2->indexWidget(idx));
            if (!combo)
            {
                combo = new QComboBox(); // make combo  
                ui.tableView_2->setIndexWidget(idx, combo);// add combo
            }
        //    combo->model()->removeRows(0, combo->count(), combo->rootModelIndex());
            colvallist1.removeDuplicates(); // clear duplicates in colvallist1
            colvallist1.removeAll(QString("")); //remove empty row data
            combo->setPlaceholderText(QString(" "));
            combo->addItems(colvallist1);
}
}

connect(ui.tableView->model(), &QAbstractItemModel::dataChanged, this,
              &cymodel::rowvalues);
```

Using removerows() all items are removed everytime,,if I added some values in column0 table1 then select in combobox and again adding values in table1 Column0 that time combobox selection go away
but if i don't use removerows() then when I'm adding new item to combobox then its adding multiple time like 2 values added then i add 2 more in table1 col then in combobox it become 4

So, how to add those that appear in colvallist1 but are not already in the combo & remove those that don't appear in colvallist1 ??

Thanks Plz help!!

Comment: any suggestion??

Comment: I'm adding items in separate loop and this code for remove already exist item,but not working correctly?if item exist  in guesslist then also it got removed ??? only one item showsing in combobox
  QStringList itemsInComboBox;
        for (int item = 0; item < combo->count(); ++item) {  //check in combobox
            itemsInComboBox << combo->itemText(item);
            for (int index = 0; index < colvallist1.count(); ++index) {  //check in list
                      if (itemsInComboBox[item]!=colvallist1[index])
                      combo->removeItem(item);
            }
        }

Comment: is it difficult question ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thnks,,,i solved this..
to remove the items in combobox which are not in colvallist1..without change in selection
here is the code--

```
void cymodel::rowvalues() {
    QAbstractItemModel* table1 = ui.tableView->model();
    QAbstractItemModel* table2 = ui.tableView_2->model();
    QStringList colvallist1;

    for (int r = 0, maxI = table1->rowCount(); r < maxI; ++r)
        colvallist1.append(table1->data(table1->index(r, 0)).toString());//store value in stringlist
        for (int i = 0, maxI = table2->rowCount(); i < maxI; ++i)//for all rows
        {
            const QModelIndex idx = table2->index(i, 1);
            QComboBox* combo1 = qobject_cast<QComboBox*>(ui.tableView_2- 
             >indexWidget(idx));
        if (!combo1)
        {
            combo1 = new QComboBox(); // make combo  
            ui.tableView_2->setIndexWidget(idx, combo);// add combo
        }
        colvallist1.removeDuplicates(); // clear duplicates in colvallist1
        colvallist1.removeAll(QString("")); //remove empty row data
        combo1->setPlaceholderText(QString(" "))
        QString selected = combo1->currentText();
        int indx = combo1->currentIndex();
        combo1->clear();
        combo1->addItems(colvallist1);
        combo1->findData(selected);
        combo1->setCurrentIndex(indx);
        combo1->setCurrentText(selected); 
      }
```